# How to avoid placing _pb2.py files at package root?

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

I'm using `libprotoc 3.2.0` with Python 3 in a Python package. If I try to the Protobuff Python files (denoted with the extensions `_pb2.py`) in to their own folder, with the `.proto` files, let's say `protobufs` and then try to import them a python file as follows:

```
# assuming outputs from a.proto and b.proto, where b depends on a
import protobufs.a
import protobufs.b
```

I get import errors that `b` can't find `a`. If I output the `_pb2.py` files into the root of my package, I don't have this problem. This is elaborated upon in [this issue](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/1491), but I'm not sure if I'm having the exact same issue or not. Is is possible to avoid outputting the `_pb2.py` files at the root of my package?

### Non-Toy Example

What I actually have is two protobuffs that reference each-other, as follows in the `.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "common.proto";
```

In the Python file, this is translated to:

```
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: persons.proto

import sys
_b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import message as _message
from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pb2
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()


import common_pb2 as common__pb2
```

But because the file is in a folder called `protobufs` in a Python package, the last line should be `import protobufs.common_pb2 as common__pb2` and not `import common_pb2 as common__pb2`, but `libprotoc` doesn't know how to take the folder into account.

Comment: Can you show how the protobuf files are referring to each other in their imports?

Comment: `init and initial_procedures` is very important cos every module got `access_rule_chain` Main module  declared an `path` if restricted `directly_call_a_sub_module` parts. You can't use module if haven't building method !

Comment: @dsgdfg can you try saying what you just said, but in a different way, while emphasizing how this relates to my question?

Comment: `common.proto` not include any path(default path = python path) so do_something before call a sub package !

Comment: @dsgdfg I'm still not following you, but I feel like you almost have an answer. What do you mean by `do_something`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is actually quite straightforward.
Simply use:

```
import "protobufs/common.proto";
```

This should cause your `_pb2.py` file to contain the import `from protobufs import common_pb2 as protobufs_dot_common__pb2` instead of the current import.

Of course, you'll need to update your compiler's command line accordingly. Something in the line of:

```
protoc.exe protobufs\persons.proto --proto_path=. --python_out=.
```

Comment: but what if the `.proto` file doesn't import other modules? How can we get the generated python `_pb2_grpc` files to import from the right package?

Comment: If the `.proto` file doesn't import other modules, then the generated python won't import either.